# Why is the join built-in having no influence on my code?

Tags: python, string, join

I had a bug that I reduced down to this:

```
a = ['a','b','c']
print( "Before", a )
" ".join(a)
print( "After", a )
```

Which outputs this:

```
runfile('C:/program.py', wdir=r'C:/')

Before ['a', 'b', 'c']
After ['a', 'b', 'c']
```

What's going on here?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[`str.join`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) does not operate in-place because string objects are immutable in Python.  Instead, it returns an entirely new string object.

If you want `a` to reference this new object, you need to explicitly reassign it:

```
a = " ".join(a)
```

Demo:

```
>>> a = ['a','b','c']
>>> print "Before", a
Before ['a', 'b', 'c']
>>> a = " ".join(a)
>>> print "After", a
After a b c
>>>
```

Comment: Jesus, I swear I tried that and got a syntax error. My bad, silly question.